# Inheriting a decorated class in Python raises TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, decorator

I would like to use a decorator (defined as a class), to decorate other classes. This seems to work just fine (see code below). But, the decorated class is inherited by a few other classes. The problem is that, when I inherit the base class, my code crashes, because of a TypeError. It says that `__init__ takes 2 positional arguments, but 4 were given`.

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, cls_):
        self.__dict__.update(cls_.__dict__)
        self.__class = cls_

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.__class(*args)

@Decorator
class Bar():
    pass

class Foo(Bar):
    pass
```

This code produces a TypeError:

> ```
> File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
>     class Foo(Bar):
> TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
> ```

I printed the arguments taken into Decorator's `__init__` method, and I got this:

```
Got called with: (<class '__main__.Bar'>,)

Got called with: ('Foo', (<__main__.Decorator object at 0x00000175E80C5490>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Foo'})
```

So yes, the Decorator's `__init__` method is called with 2 more arguments. But I don't really understand why, or what I could do in order to make it work.

Long story short: I can decorate a class (Bar), but inheriting from that class (e.g.: Foo) raises a TypeError, because it's getting called with 2 more arguments. I don't know what those 2 arguments represent or how I could make it work.

Do you have any suggestions of how I could succeed in inheriting the decorated base class? I'm interested in also keeping the functionality of the decorator and the base class, of course.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you need a decorator? what is your goal? maybe a metaclass is what you are looking for?

Comment: use `*args` and/or `**kwargs`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist - I would like to have a context manager to manage some of my errors for the Bar class. The Foo class is then inherited by other classes. My best idea was using a decorator to decorate the base class (Bar). I don't know any other way.

Comment: @JacobIRR Yes, I thought about using *args and/or **kwargs, but I don't know which arguments from the *args list to use for the child class (Foo). The first argument when decorating the Bar class is <class '__main__.Bar'>, but with Foo it's just a string (check the output from the __init__ method). How could I get the same thing for Foo, as I get for Bar?

Comment: Use kwargs and check its keys like a dictionary to see which values are coming in (if they are being passed in at all)

Comment: @JacobIRR I am unable to check the arguments using the **kwargs keyword, because the arguments are not passed by key-value. I can only see the arguments if I use *args.

Comment: Args should work for you then.

Comment: In the first case, the argument passed is a class. In the second case, it's a string. So *args helps me with finding out how the decorator method is called, but I don't know what to do from there. I just have the 'Foo' string, I cannot point it to the 'Foo' class because it's not even created at that point.